# How to solve the general sextic equation with Kampé de Fériet functions?

Tags: polynomials, special-functions, hypergeometric-function, theta-functions

It is frequently stated, for example on [Wolfram Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SexticEquation.html), that the general sextic equation

$$x^6 + a_5 x^5 + a_4 x^4 + a_3 x^3 + a_2 x^2 + a_1 x^1 + a_0 = 0$$

can be solved in terms of Kampé de Fériet functions - however the explicit solution is hard to find.

How can one solve the general sextic equation with Kampé de Fériet functions (or indeed other functions)?

Comment: I hope this may help http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1313118/solutions-of-sixth-order-polynomial-equations

Comment: The general sextic first has to be reduced to the form $x^6+x^2+ax+b = 0$, then one solves it by the two-variable Kampé de Fériet functions. But I've never seen a specific example in all this time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in brief (I need to go catch a train), here are the links to the papers cited on the MathWorld page. They are all open domain (published more than a century ago!)

Here is the link for the [first paper cited on the MathWorld page](http://download.springer.com/static/pdf/186/art%253A10.1007%252FBF01564501.pdf?originUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flink.springer.com%2Farticle%2F10.1007%2FBF01564501&token2=exp=1458801056~acl=%2Fstatic%2Fpdf%2F186%2Fart%25253A10.1007%25252FBF01564501.pdf%3ForiginUrl%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flink.springer.com%252Farticle%252F10.1007%252FBF01564501*~hmac=01e60cd1a99180265722a9286b87f523b0605897f34f4e1ef939444239f6f232)

Similarly here is the [second paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1911-012-03/S0002-9947-1911-1500891-5/S0002-9947-1911-1500891-5.pdf) by Coble on the subject.

And finally, the [last paper](https://archive.org/details/jstor-2369410) Weisstein cites.

This is [a paper on solution methods](http://www.ijpam.eu/contents/2005-23-4/9/9.pdf) for sextics in general.

And if any of the links fails, a simple Google search should reveal the original paper.

I am not sure if an explicit solution is to be found in any of these papers, but if one cannot be deduced, then the Wolfram MathWorld page on the subject has a problem of its own!